# Trigger a lightbox modal on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I would like to get a lightbox modal box to pop up automatically on page load.

My current anchor works perfect when I actually click it, and here is my bit of JQuery that I've been using so far.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      document.getElementById('popup').click();
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<a id="popup" class="wb-lbx lbx-modal" href="#alert">test</a>
      <section id="alert" class="mfp-hide modal-dialog modal-content overlay-def">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
          <h2 class="h4">header</h2>
          <p>content</p>
          </div>
      </section>
```

Problem is, it just brings me to the #popup anchor location on the page, not actually triggering the lightbox that pops if you were to actually click it.

How do I trigger the click event on page load?

Thanks

Comment: provide your html code, fiddle will be better

Comment: have you tried window.load() function perhaps?

Comment: $("#popup").trigger("click"); will make it work

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal?

Comment: _"My current anchor works perfect when I actually click it"_ What code do you have that accomplishes that?

Comment: That's the class wb-lbx and lbx-modal... it calls in lightbox and does it's thing...the joy of working in a large firm where people decide to lobotimize plugins for "safety"...

Comment: $("#popup").trigger("click"); isn't working.